# Rails: create model for existing controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a basic app which consists of a controller containing only one method. The method connects to an API which returns several hashes (in an array). After some manipulation, new hashes are written to a different array. The view iterates over the new array and builds a table to display the contents of each hash.

Controller:

```
class VlanManagerController < ApplicationController
  require 'fog'
  require 'ipaddress'

  def connect

    @vlans = Array.new

    connection = Fog::Compute.new(
      provider: 'Ecloud',
      ecloud_access_key: '#*#*#*#*#*#*#',
      ecloud_private_key: '*#*#*#*#*#*#*',
      ecloud_version: '2014-03-01'
    )

    networks = connection.get_organization("/cloudapi/ecloud/networks/environments/######").body

    networks[:Network].each do |hash|
      ip = IPAddress(hash[:name])
      netmask = ip.netmask
      hosts = ip.hosts.map {|host| host.address }
      gateway = hosts[0]

      @vlans << {vlan: hash[:Description], network: hash[:name], netmask: netmask, gateway: gateway}
    end
  end
end
```

View:

```
<h1>VLAN Manager v0.01</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>VLAN</th>
    <th>Network</th>
    <th>Netmask</th>
    <th>Gateway</th>
    </th>
  <tr>
<% @vlans.each do |hash| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= hash[:vlan] %></td>
      <td><%= hash[:network] %></td>
      <td><%= hash[:netmask] %></td>
      <td><%= hash[:gateway] %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

I now want to add a model which will contain a table to which all of these hashes will be written instead of being written out to a browser as an HTML table.

If I create a model will all of the necessary infrastructure be created with it or will I have to do more than just run `rails generate model ...`? Would it make more sense to start a new rails app and generate scaffolding instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can create any model with required name and create columns as you like. I think so best way is controller name should be `VlanManagers` .

Ex:

`rails g model VlanManager name:string`

adding a record

```
VlanManager.create(:name => "prasad")
```

retrive all records

```
VlanManager.all
```